# The TLF (Text Layout Framework) is deprecated, what to do now?

Tags: flash, arabic, tlf

"The Text Layout Framework is deprecated and the functionality will be unavailable with Flash Professional CC. If a FLA file containing TLF Text, previously saved with an older version of Flash Professional, is opened with Flash Pro CC, then TLF is converted to Classic Text. For more information, see this article."

Okay.

And now what?? we need to use Arabic(Hebrew...) fonts, are we stuck with Flash CS6 for ever??

Answer (score 4):

I used a trick and it works

1- Copy two (.swc) files from flash cs6 or cs5 (support tlf text)

- textLayout.swc
- tlfruntime.swc

2- Paste them into( Adobe Flash CC \Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\libs)

3- Restart flash

4- Use the TLFTextField method

```
      import fl.text.TLFTextField;

      var txt:TLFTextField = new TLFTextField ;
      txt.text = "النص العربي";
     addChild(txt);
```

5- Make sure to embed font to the library .

Comment: By using this methode, will Adobe Flash CC keep on transforming TLF texts on stage to regular text fields automatically?

Comment: yes just import it and that's it. I used it with adobe flash cc and adobe flash cc 2014 and it works fine the problem is it takes more time to manipulate your text size and format but it works .It would be easer to use cs6 instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are few working solutions to this like text classes and extensions but one easy way is to keep Flash Cs5 or 6 installed and make texts on it then import them as swf files.

Comment: Working with right to left text (arabic..) is already a hard task, I cant imagine loading and managing dynamic text with the available extensions, TLF in flash was a great solution(with all the bugs..). I am surprised about this decision, am I the only one who still using Adobe Flash?
Can you suggest the name of the classes and extensions you was talking about?

Comment: I don't know the name but I'm sure you can find something by searching in arabic websites who do flash design oriented talk.
IMHO use TLF by loading swf and avoid all of the pain searching.

Comment: No, you are not the only one using Flash.  Flash is the most incredible Web technology I've ever seen.  The TLF was a disaster, IMO.  It should have been a native class like a normal TextField, and instead they tried to some kind of runtime preloading that turned out to be a complicated mess.  There were hacks like the undocumented ProLoader class which "must" be used for child SWFs that use TLF, and even once you get such text loaded, it would, for example, display the wrong font until you clicked the text field.  I'm so glad they got rid of it in CC.  Hopefully they will fix it.

Comment: See my thread here on how terrible the TLF is.  I wouldn't be surprised if I personally caused them to deprecate it: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1224779

Comment: You have no idea about the capability of TLF. It's not just the center container align, images...  Maybe you are like others don't have a reason to use TLF, but for us, the other part of the planet, Arabs Asians... its the only way to load dynamic text! how a company like Adobe don't provide a solution for us since 2005! TLF was a savior for those who still believe in flash (it takes us 2 days to find out about the ProLoader  joke...)