# as3 air mobile input text for arabic content

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, input, air, arabic

I'm developing an AIR mobile application (iOS and Android) for the middle-east market.
I'm trying to "create" input textfield that support the arabic font and the RTL direction:

- (classic) TextField doesn't support the RTL direction
- TLFTextField supports RTL direction but doesn't work properly on mobile devices (at least, on iOS devices: softkeyboard isn't shown)
- StageText is perfect for mobile devices but it seems doesn't support RTL direction (I don't know about the arabic font)

Did someone has never been in this situation? Which could be a solution? I'm a bit demoralized...

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212039/the-tlf-text-layout-framework-is-deprecated-what-to-do-now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Adobe Air bug, see this links:

[Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5210263)

[Bug](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3693360)

They said if a lot of user vote for this they will solve it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know too much about Arabic language so I hope my assumption that RTL is the only distinction is correct. In that case you can easily 'trick' the textfield like this:

```
var t:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(t);
//...set text format if you need/want to
t.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onTextChange);

function onTextChange(e:Event):void {
    t.setSelection(0, 0);
}
```

I assume you will want to align the textfield to the right.

Answer (score 0):

FlarabyAS3 might help:
http://www.arabicode.com/content/flarabyas3

or use FTE:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/engine/package-detail.html