# SWF file not opening in IE

Tags: flash, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, flash-cs5.5

I have developed a flash presentation using Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5 with no scripts inside it. It just contains a bunch of images spread over the timeline and a music file.

When I open in IE8, I am receiving the below errors:

```
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flashx.textLayout.container::TextContainerManager could not be found.

ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Icon is not defined.

ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable FLVPlayback is not defined.

ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Font_2 is not defined.

ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable MainTimeline is not defined.
```

After clicking continue for all errors, only a black screen is coming.

But when opening the same SWF in Google chrome, it is working fine.

---

**These are the Flash player versions:**

For IE8: 11.5

For Google Chrome: 11.8 (In Which it is working fine)

I also tested in IE9 with flash player version 13 and it is having no problem with this as well.

In another system, with IE8 and Flash 11.3, SWF is opening but not playing chrome with flash version 11.8

---

I am totally confused with the things happening around this.

Can anyone help me with this issue? Or Redirect me to some place where I can find flash experts, if it is not the correct place to post the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with publishing settings. The swf file which is published using cs5.5 is supported by Flash players 10 & 12 but not by 11. So, when I changed the publish settings and set the flash player version to Lite4 with action scrpt3 (Other wise sound will not play), it is working fine with all the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

> VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flashx.textLayout.container

This suggests you are using [TLF text](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/concept_tlf_text.html) which is not necessary in most cases, and [officially depreciated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212039/the-tlf-text-layout-framework-is-deprecated-what-to-do-now). Since you have Flash CS5, change your target player to Flash Player 9, and press OK. This forces all TLF text in the FLA to be replaced with normal TextFields. Then you can upgrade to Flash Player 10/11 in Publish settings and all will be fine.