# How to save a flash movie in html format

Tags: adobe, flash, flash-cs5.5

I have developed a flash movie using flash professional CS5.5 and exported the movie to SWF file. But I am having trouble in viewing this file in all browsers (Posted the question here: [SWF file not opening in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074397/swf-file-not-opening-in-ie)). I don't have the option of installing higher version of flash player in my system as all the systems are in my office. I wanted to know if it is possible to save this movie in a different format which is light weight like SWF, so that i want this to be embedded in a website.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you