# Text Styling from Flash Professional to Animate

Tags: flash, adobe

So, I imagine that this is a simple question, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

I'm pretty familiar with how Adobe Flash Professional worked and I've played in it for years learning AS2 and AS3 and creating little apps and games.

Today, I finally made the transition to Adobe Animate (finally, right??), and I can't figure out the simplest of things. Most importantly, I'm trying to style a dynamic text box. When I create it, it's got a white background. Now those styling options used to be in the Properties window, where I could add a border and change its style, color, width, add background color, font color, but it seems like some of those styles have been moved or removed and I don't know where to find them.

Links to good tutorials would be great too, since I'm finding little to nothing, probably because my searches include the word "animate" and that's probably too vague...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like the functionality was indeed removed from CC (https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/text-layout-framework-tlf-text.html). Now that I know that what I was looking for was "TLF" text or "Text Layout Framework", my search was able to turn up better results. This guy --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212039/the-tlf-text-layout-framework-is-deprecated-what-to-do-now seems to have the same issue, and his only answers were to keep older versions of Flash on your computer, which is a shitty work-around (pardon my French).

Answer (score 0):

Those properties are still there for me. Did you create a new ActionScript 3.0 file or an HTML 5 Canvas file? HTML 5 Canvas still has a lot of tools and properties missing, and if you're working in that most likely the reason for the lacking feature set.

[image]
[image]

*Above, ActionScript 3.0 on the left, HTML 5 Canvas on the right*

Comment: Thank you, but no. I guess after a bit of digging, I'm referring to the "Container and Flow" section of what was called the TLF text from the CS5+ version of Flash: http://flashthusiast.com/2010/04/23/flash-cs5-screenshot-tour/ That also allowed us to change the padding, background and border colors of the text box itself. But I also find that when I create a dynamic or input text, it has a white background and I can't get rid of it. I guess it was removed in CC?

Comment: Yep - they removed TLF text. The white background might be a property? Does it remain white when compiled or only in the editor?

Comment: It showed up as white in both. I experimented yesterday going back to the old days where you had to change them programmatically in AS3 like so: myTextField.backgroundColor = "#ebebeb"; It's rather annoying, but I guess that's what we have to do when the UI options are not available anymore. It's inspired me to write a reference sheet of all the TLF text features that went missing, and how to fix them in CC because having an older version of Flash is not an acceptable solution for me. So I'll be doing that soon.